# listview always removes last item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I try to remove a specific item from a listView but it's always remove the last item.
I create a custom adapter to my listview.
I try to search for a solution and i found some posts about this problem but I still didn't success to solve the problem

custom adapter below:

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
public static final String WORD_COLUMN="First";
public static final String TRAN_COLUMN="Second";
Activity activity;
TextView txtFirst;
TextView txtSecond;
public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super();
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

    if(convertView == null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_row, null);

        txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wordColumn);
        txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tranColumn);
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(WORD_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(TRAN_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

activity code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashList;
private ListViewAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.gvWords);

    hashList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, hashList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    onClickButtons();
}

public void onClickButtons()
{
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            hashList.remove(i);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Thank's :)

Comment: Your `ListViewAdapter` code is not complete. Please post all the overridden methods of `BaseAdapter` like `getCount()`, `getItem()` etc that you have included in `ListViewAdapter`

Comment: How does it remove the correct item in the list but not the adapter? The listview has one less item. The bottom element moves up, but should not be removed

Comment: Remove the `if(convertView == null){`, and see what happens

Comment: I tried to remove the `if(convertView == null){` and it's work! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access and remove clicked object via `getItemAtPosition(position)` and then remove it from ArrayList via `.remove(Object o)`

Your listener will therefore look like this:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            hashList.remove(lv.getItemAtPosition(i));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

This approach is mentioned in official doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

> Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Comment: It's success to remove the item from the hashlist correctly, the problem is the removal from the listview, it's always remove the last item from the listview but it's remove the correct hash from the hashlist

Answer (score 0):

> after refreshing it's remove the right item

You've cached the two TextViews, which aren't updated as part of notifying the adapter.

Alter the convertView check and remove those fields, then lookup how to implement the ViewHolder pattern (or use a RecyclerView)

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem,

and removed the `if(convertView == null){` It's working,

Please let us know for this reason.